# Can I output sound from a MiniNova into a combo audio jack, and record it with Audacity?

Tags: audacity

I have a Novation MiniNova and I want to try and record the sounds I play on it. Since it seems to be able to output sound into any aux input, is it possible to output it into a "combo" audio jack and then record it in Audacity?

Comment: what do you mean by a 'combo' audio jack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'combo audio jack' I assume you mean the 3.5 mm TRRS jack (for stereo headphones plus mono microphone) common on PCs.

Yes, this is possible, with some caveats.

- You can only record in mono.
- You need to connect the 1/4" jack on the MiniNova with the 3.5 mm TRRS jack on the PC. The easiest way to achieve this is via a 1/4" to 3.5 mm cable (mono or stereo, makes no difference for this application), and a TRRS jack splitter (which splits into a stereo TRS 3.5 mm for the computer outputs (headphones) and a mono 3.5 mm (computer input).
  There are [2 different pinouts for TRRS](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/), so make sure you get a splitter that's right for your application.
- On the PC, set the microphone level to a low level, and test how much signal you're getting. Adjust the mic level until you get a signal that's strong enough without clipping.
- There is some potential for ground loops. If you get a 50/60 Hz hum or other noise in the audio, get a DI box and plug this in between the synth and the PC (either a passive DI, or an active DI that can be powered by an adapter).

Comment: Would the same be possible if I were to plug a jack splitter into the combo jack, and then output the sound from the synth into the microphone section of it?

Comment: yes, if you get the correct splitter this is possible. My initial answer had some incorrect info, so I had to change it.